# Efficiently reshape/reorder numpy array from (a, b, c) to (a, c, b)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several Numpy 3D arrays of the shape (`a`, `b`, `c`). The values of `a`, `b`, and `c` are unknown. However, I want to reshape each of the arrays to (`a`, `c`, `b`) in an efficient way.

Here is what I am doing:

```py
for array in list_of_arrays:
    a, b, c = array.shape
    array = array.reshape(a, c, b)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, possibly in **one line** of code? Can I use the `-1` indexing method to reshape/reorder the arrays?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand where you want to improve efficiency. `array.shape` isn't slow, so what does changing it to one line of code do? You can use `np.moveaxis` or `np.swapaxis` but that's not going to make your code faster. Why do you have a list of arrays instead of a large array that you can operate on at once?

Comment: Each 3D array is different and should be operated on independently. Hence, I stored them as a list rather than as a large 4D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `np.transpose`? It swaps all dimensions to the specified order.

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 80, 3))

np.transpose(x, (1, 0, 2))
```

```
(80, 100, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I can transpose each array in a list comprehension.

Comment: Yes, or with the `map()` function.

Comment: Have you considered accepting an answer? Let us know if we can improve our answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# Example array with shape (2, 4, 6)    
array = np.arange(48).reshape((2, 4, 6))

# Swap axis in the 1st and 2nd dimension and print out its shape     
np.swapaxis(array, 1, 2).shape
```

Output:

```
(2, 6, 4)
```